# Execute a python script as a command

Tags: python, unix

I'm writing a python script which will be placed in a location. I want to execute it just like a command. for ex.

```
$ find_branch test
```

where find_branch is a script placed in anywhere in the system.

I would like to know how to achieve this. I can run it on the place where the script is present by chmod u+x on the script and removing the .py from the script

Comment: Why couldn't you run "python <path_to_script>"?

Comment: Just place `#!/usr/bin/python` (or wherever your Python is located) in the first line and set the executable bit.

Comment: You need to add the directory it is in to your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: More detail, please.  Can we assume that this is a Unix system (you mentioned chmod)?

Comment: It is a good idea to not place scripts "anywhere" but in trusted or well-known locations that can then be added to your search path.

Comment: I think you are contradicting yourself when you say "writing a python script which will be placed in a location" and "find_branch is a script placed anywhere in the system"

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/testpyscript
```

Then inside the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("I'm a python script")
```

Give it `x` permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/testpyscript
```

Now you can use it as a regular command:

```
bash-4.2$ testpyscript 
I'm a python script
```

It doesn't have to be exactly at `/usr/bin`, any location that is inside your $PATH will do. Let's say you want it to be located at some folder inside your home directory, you could do something like this:

```
pwd
/home/brunorb

mkdir somedir
sudo mv /usr/bin/testpyscript somedir/

export PATH=$PATH:/home/brunorb/somedir/

testpyscript # from any folder in the system
I'm a python script
```

Comment: But you still have to cd to /path/to/script/. I believe OP's question is how to avoid that (i.e. adding a script to the $PATH).

Comment: The OP said he wants to the script to be "placed anywhere in the system" but your answer requires him to put it in a specific place

Comment: It's just an example, usually all linux have /usr/bin in $PATH by default, I commented in the last line that it can be anywhere as long the dir is in you $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options on how to achieve this.

1. Add the location where you put the script to your `PATH` environment variable, for example in your `~/.bashrc` script:

   ```
   export PATH="${PATH}:/folder/where/you/put/the/script"
   ```
2. Install the script to a location that is already on your path. It does not have to be a system folder like `/usr/bin`. Many default Bash setups will include `~/bin` in your `PATH`.
3. Give the full path to your script on the command line:

   ```
   /folder/where/you/put/the/script/find_branch test
   ```
4. Run the script through Python. This is very similar to option #2:

   ```
   python /folder/where/you/put/the/script/find_branch test
   ```
5. Create an alias for the script in your environment. In bash you would do something like the following in your `~/.bashrc`:

   ```
   alias find_branch='/folder/where/you/put/the/script/find_branch'
   ```

   OR

   ```
   alias find_branch='python /folder/where/you/put/the/script/find_branch'
   ```

For options #1, #2, #3 and #5a to work properly, you should have a shebang with the version of python as the first line of the script. Any of the following will do, depending on how you have/want your environment set up:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python2
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Finally, you do not have to remove the `.py` extension from the script if you do not want to. Many bash scripts have a `.sh` extension, for example, which does not prevent them from running as-is. You just have to include the extension in the name of the script when you run it.

Comment: I think 3 and 5a will need the shebang as well

Comment: @Holloway. Yessir. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure python has been added to your path and `#!/usr/bin/python` is located at the top of your script.

**Note** You could just try adding your script to your `/usr/local/bin/` directory and give it the proper permissions.

`sudo cp <your script> /usr/local/bin/`